# AngularJS Custom Directive based on class expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am attempting to utilize nested custom directives to produce a complete survey form. A custom survey tag contains repeated group tags that contain repeated question tags. Different question types will be handled by separate directives based on their type ID. The question directives look for a elements with a class that matches the question type ID.

```
<div ng-repeat='q in g.questions track by $index' class='{{q.squt_id}}'>...</div>
```

I believe the problem is that the expression is being evaluated after the directives are applied. Any thoughts or ideas here? I am locked into using the type ID as the unique way to determine question types.

```
app.directive('1',function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a base directive, use it for every type and pass the type ID as a parameter. Then in the directive you can create a `switch`, use  `ng-if`, dynamically add the type directive name in the base directive template or anything else.

I don't think that you can dynamically add the directive name in the view.

Comment: you can dynamically add directives (via attributes & classes) however it would require that they forego the typical *transclusion* process by utilizing the `$compile` service in their `link` function.  It's not a trivial task in the least bit, ergo why your suggestion is probably better suited for his problem.